# jQuery fadeOut and fadeIn not working on live site, fadeOut/fadeIn going faster than my actual picture can change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created this simple website with this script...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var photos = ["indexphotos/1.jpg", "indexphotos/2.jpg", "indexphotos/3.jpg", "indexphotos/4.jpg",
            "indexphotos/5.jpg"];
    var currentPhoto = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#content img').fadeOut(400, function() {
            if(currentPhoto == 5) {
                currentPhoto = 0;
            }
            $('#content img').attr("src",photos[currentPhoto]);
            currentPhoto++;
            $('#content img').fadeIn(400);
        });
    },5000);
</script>
```

To have a slideshow that plays and fades in and out photos looping through 5 photos. It worked fine while I was developing it locally, but now when it is live on a server it is having hiccups. It will fadeout but then go back to the same picture, then eventually switch to the new picture even though it was suppose to switch to the picture before it fades back in. Like the fadein and fadeout is faster than the actual changing the picture.

If you refresh the page though once, it works fine.

Is there a way to do this better so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an `onload` handler for the image, that would fade-in only after image has been loaded (after changing the `src`)

```
$("#content img").one("load", function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(); //fade in after loading image
}).attr("src", whatever); //change ti another image
```

PS. `.one` is not a typo here.